# Which model relationship should be used here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Table: Raw_Data
Fields: id
        name

Table: Actual_Data
Fields: id
        raw_data_id
        name

A use can either add data manually to Actual_Data (in which case it's raw_data_id is NULL) or they can select a Raw_Data to insert into Actual_Data (in which case it's raw_data_id is set).

Is the following relationships correct in this case?

For Raw_Data:
-none-

For Actual_Data:
has_one :raw_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the relationship should be the same as you said,

```
class ActualDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :raw_data
end

class RawData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :actual_data
end
```

As per the rails convention, the foreign key should belongs to the table which has belongs_to association, so here actual_data_id should be in raw_datas table.

Edit:
We don't need raw_data_id in actual_datas table.

Comment: Only some of the Raw_Data's will ever be added to Actual_Data. Would that be an issue? (Since some raw_data entries will never be used and not have a foreign key association).

Comment: It should not be an issue as long as you do a nil check before using raw_data of any actual_data object. For eg: actual_data.raw_data && actual_data.raw_data.id will never break.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better option is belongs_to.

```
Raw_Data has many or has one Actual_Data
Actual_Data belongs to Raw Data.
```

You just have to remember to check if raw_data is nil before doing any operations.

```
manually_created = ActualData.create(:name => "Something");
builded = @RawData.build_actual_data(:name => "Something else");
```

The first will have the column set to null, and the second exaple, will set raw_data_id to @RawData.id value.